# Problem with App store connect, They say I have a HealthKit but I don't

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store

I submitted an application to the app store and received this message

> We noticed that your app uses HealthKit, but your app does not appear to include any primary features that require health or fitness data.
> The intended use of HealthKit is generally to share health or fitness data with other apps or devices as a part of the app's core functionality.
> Next Steps
> To resolve this issue, please remove any HealthKit functionality from your app, as well as any references to this app’s interactivity with HealthKit from the app or its metadata. This includes removing any HealthKit-related keys in your app's Info.plist as well as removing any calls to HealthKit APIs, including those from 3rd party platforms, from your app.

But I analyzed my code, previously developed by another company and I can't find any reference to HealthKit

Here is my info.plist

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>---</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>---</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.5.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.5.0.4</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LauchScreenSB</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>---</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>---</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>---</string>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>--- File</string>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>com.apple.ostype</key>
                <string>SCAN</string>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>scan</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>application/octet-stream</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>lightContent</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>---</string>
    <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To scan documents this app needs to access your camera. .</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable microphone access so that you can add voice comments to your scans</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to Photos in order to save your scans.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to Photos in order to save your scans.</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>pt</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>pt</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to Calendar in order to show some information on calendar.</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to Contacts to see user information. No data is saved.</string>
    <key>kTCCServiceMediaLibrary</key>
    <string>This app need access to Music to reproduce some sounds.</string>
    <key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to Siri to be showen on Siri results. </string>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app need access to Media to reproduce some sounds.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

here are my references

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AForge" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="AForge.Math" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="portable.aforge.core" version="2.2.5.60302" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="portable.aforge.imaging" version="2.2.5.50513" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="portable.aforge.math" version="2.2.5.60302" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="shim" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="shim.drawing" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugins.Settings" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
</packages>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Make sure that you had  closed the HealthKit  in `Entitlements.plist` i your project and in your apple developing account .

Comment: What option is the linker mode set to?

Comment: I already try the Don't link and Link Framework SDKs Only, but I have the same result in app store connect

Comment: You could post the issue to apple official forums . The issue seems didn't caused by xamarin .